# Unable to Install Homebrew; Failed during: git fetch --force origin

Tags: mac, homebrew, git

I'm having an installation problem with Homebrew; it involves git

I ran the command from my terminal, M1pro, with git installed.
I tried to do use `port` but I was unable to install it
I tried to do `git global url insteadOf(https:// for git:// or @git) setup` but it still doesn't work.
This is the error from terminal:

```
amaku@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R amaku:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: remote error: 
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

The blog says there's a security update, idk?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is purely related to Git. There are a couple of tricks like updating global configurations of git like these;

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

#### Better alternative

If the above doesn't work, delete the directory `sudo rm -r /usr/local/Homebrew`, then I recommend installing brew using the pkg installer;

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/latest